# How do I add structured data for Google Webmaster Tools?

Tags: google-search-console, structured-data, weebly

I used Weebly to build my website. My site is 'on' Google, but GWT is saying it can't detect any structured data.

Where and how do I do this? I understand what it is but don't know how to go about doing it.

Comment: What package did you use? Also, have you seen [this](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2650907).

Comment: I actually used weebly! I have read through the schema webpage, but I'm just not sure where to enter any of the html codes etc.

Answer (score 1):

This [article](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170) from Google describes it well. In short:

1. Pick a markup format (microdata, microformtats, RDFa).
2. Mark up your content according, for example using the formats described on http://www.schema.org/.
3. Test your markup with the [structured data testing tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets).

For example, if you have a product on your site you need to wrap some custom HTML around it. Look at the example at the bottom of the [product](http://www.schema.org/Product) page, or for an even simpler example:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <span itemprop="name">Kenmore White 17" Microwave</span>
  <img src="kenmore-microwave-17in.jpg" alt='Kenmore 17" Microwave' />

  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <span itemprop="price">$55.00</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

All the divs and spans are the extra stuff added to make it structured.

Comment: Hi, thanks. How do I do the 'marking up' bit. Do I go to the Custom HTML section on my site editor? Thanks

Comment: Probably. Without knowing which software package you use, and what sort of data you want to mark up I can't be more specific.

Comment: I used weebly to design my website. I think I need to turn my page and product descriptions into structured data. But I haven't really got a clue what I am talking about!

Comment: I've updated my answer. You do need to understand a bit of HTML to make sure it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

there is now a better option: use the Structured Data Highlighter on a typical page to graphically show where structured data is, GWT will then assume pages with similar structure have the same elements needing structured data, no need to code anymore.

The option is just below the one that lists you see the Structured Data GWT has/hasn't been able to find.